# Building solution reverts MySQL stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, mysql, stored-procedures

I've been scratching my head over this problem for nearly a day now and I just simply cannot figure out what's wrong. Any ideas / suggestions would be very helpful!

**The background**

I've been tasked with getting an intranet developed by another developer up and running with the final touches before release. The developer before me has been using stored procedures for pretty much every database-call, so to keep this time effective I'm more or less forced to follow the set architecture and "live with it".

**System info**
MySQL 5.5.27 , .NET 4.5 , Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 on dev machine

**The problem**

It seems that sometimes when I build the app-solution, every single stored procedure in the database seems to revert back to their original state. All changes I've made to *all* SP's are simply gone and there's nothing in the logs that states there's been a rollback or revert of any kind.

This happens on both my local DB on this machine, as well as an off-site server I tested it on.

I simply cannot figure out what's going wrong and why it's doing these reverts completely at random. Sidenote: The data and table structure within the database(s) remains completely untouched.

The only thing I can think of is that the former developer has implemented a function within the app to create the stored procedures upon runtime, thus "reverting" them when I build/publish it. Where do I even begin looking for it if this might be the case?

Comment: Put on my "what would I do if I was going to lose my job"-trousers, and sure enough there's an absolute smackton of obfuscated code within the global.asax file that together forms a 30k+ character string - which then get's thrown into this: command = new MySqlCommand(strCmd, connection);

I suppose my question now should be: Should I try to find the randomizer that causes it to run at seemingly random, or simply bite the bullet and re-write it all?

Comment: i had a very bad experiencewith VS and mysql , the better way is dont use VS IDE as connector view for mysql. this thing is pure burden and bugged when using with mysql(looks like microsoft guys needed a hidden trap for anything that is free :X) ; thats why i use admin tools of mysql when working on such projects.

Comment: I was looking at the extensions for VS but decided to give up due to it being nothing but rubbish in the end. I'm building and benching with MySql Workbench which as of now fulfill my needs. As for the question itself, I made a few more runs at it today and the error definitely lies in the global.asax file and the project files.

Comment: good that it worked out for you. @Bonius